# GTK+ Placing notebook tabs on top of the toolbar/oher widget

Tags: c, gtk

I am using GTK+ programming in C in ubuntu 11.10 oneiric ocelot.

i have a notebook widget (gtk_notebook) which is placed in the middle of the content.I have other widgets included such as a menubar and some other ones.My question is if its posible to draw/place the tabs of the notebook in a place i will set to (for example under the menubar or on the top of the toolbar (for example when i place the widgets in my vertical box i have gtk_box_pack_start(menubar, notebook_tabs, custom_widget, toolbar, notebook)).Is that possible at all or will i have to push GTK to the limit and make something more different and exhausting like creating my own widget that looks like notebook or something like that?Any suggestions/guidelines are very,very aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by hiding the notebook tabs and changing the notebook page in response to a button click on another widget.

To hide the tabs:

```
gtk_notebook_set_show_tabs(GTK_NOTEBOOK(view), FALSE);
```

Then, when adding the page, don't give it a label:

```
int pageId = gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(view), GTK_WIDGET(page), NULL);
```

You can then select the page using:

```
gtk_notebook_set_current_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK(view), pageId);
```

You can do this on a `GtkToggleButton`'s toggle handler, with some logic to get the correct button to be active.

If you place these in a `GtkBox`, in Gtk+ 3 you can attach a name to it:

```
layout = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
gtk_widget_set_name(layout, "navbar");
```

and use CSS to style it and the hosted buttons (e.g. `#navbar button { color: red; }`). Alternatively, you can associate a class to the widget:

```
GtkStyleContext *context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(layout);
gtk_style_context_add_class(layout, "tabbed");
```

and use CSS to style it and the hosted buttons (e.g. `.tabbed button { color: red; }`).

If you look at the Adwaita gtk3 CSS theme, you can add the styles and classes associated with the tab bar section to get it styled correctly, or load a user-based CSS style theme to get the look correct.

If you can use GPLv3 code, I am doing something like this in:

1. https://github.com/rhdunn/cainteoir-gtk/blob/master/src/navbar.hpp
2. https://github.com/rhdunn/cainteoir-gtk/blob/master/src/navbar.cpp
3. https://github.com/rhdunn/cainteoir-gtk/blob/master/src/cainteoir.cpp (which creates the `GtkNotebook` and places the buttons in the `navbar`)

Comment: Wow that is indeed a great answer and i really nice method to implement that!!Thanks a lot,i haven't tried that for now,when i do i may post a reply at the thread to tell you/others if that does the job or not :) Thanks again!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to separate the notebook tabs from the notebook. But it's really not that hard to create a custom widget...

Comment: thanks a bunch for your help,could you give me an example-guideline on how i could achieve that?